# Do not filter search results by tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, search

Due to a problem encountered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10485/search-results-appear-and-then-promptly-disappear-on-stackoverflow), I would like to request that search results are not filtered based on our ignored tag list.

Currently the filtering aids some benefit in removing questions that may not be relevant to what we're looking for, so if I search `[sql]` and have `[c#]` filtered, all questions dealing with `[sql]` for C# would be removed for me. However I argue that being able to use more specific searches would benefit users more in the general case. If I wanted to find sql dealing only with php, I could search `[sql]` `[php]` and get the desired results.

For these reasons searches should be exempt from active filtering. If I need to search something that is usually against my interests, I may not be able to find and it. It may never be apparent that it is being filtered out, which then leads me to the assumption that it simply does not exist. The current implementation can also lead to the creation of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate this by using the google search, which will ignore your tags altogether. Also as far as I know ignoring tags is not enforced when going directly to a question, so you would be able to view the question and answer.

More details on using Google Search [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/what-are-some-good-tips-for-searching-stackoverflow)

Comment: I realize the problem and solution, hence it's a feature request not a bug.

Comment: Fair enough. However mentioned this for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to temporarely disable the ignore list is to just log out before doing the search, and then log in again afterwords.

---

The best solution however would be to [merge the ignore and interesting lists into one list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/provide-keep-interesting-tags-option-when-hide-ignored-tags-enabled/59666#59666). That way you can give sql:interesting higher priority than C#:ignore and not have any need to temporarely disable filtering.

Answer (score 0):

After the latest round of search changes, interesting and ignored tags no longer applies to the results page.