# Please show me the messages of a tag on the "Ignored-Tags-List" when I explicitly ask for a [tag]

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not filter search results by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10520/do-not-filter-search-results-by-tag)

**GOOD:** Putting a tag into the "Ignored Tags" category hides all questions tagged that way.

Selecting / viewing an "ignored tag" explicitly (e.g. the [ [ignore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ignore) ] tag) shows an empty list (ignore - attribute is applied)

**WISH:** Please show me the messages of a tag on the "Ignored-Tags-List" when I explicitly ask for a [tag].

---

**EDIT**

I am not talking about the search box [ **a** ]. I'm talking about explicitly clicking on a tag displayed [ **b** ]. A different usecase

- a: http: // meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ignore
- b: http: // meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10520/do-not-filter-search-results-by-tag

Comment: @Ian Elliott : I disagree, that question is about filtering search results where one of the tags is on the ignore list. I'm asking to not filter when going for "taged". That will not display two tags at the same time.

Comment: yeah, ignored/interesting tags usability is deteriorating rapidly :(

Comment: No, it's the same issue. Search [ignore] and tell me what page you end up on.